# R: how to merge values in 2 different length time-series columns

Tags: r

I have two dfs, df4 and df3.2 below:

```
head(df4)
  visits first_date
1      0 2013-09-21
2      0 2013-09-28
3      0 2013-10-05
4      0 2013-10-12
5      0 2013-10-19
6      0 2013-10-26

head(df3.2)
  visits first_date
1      1 2013-10-19
2      1 2013-11-09
3      1 2013-11-16
4      1 2013-12-07
5      1 2013-12-21
6      1 2013-12-28
```

df4 has a consecutive first date of the week column w/ 158 rows while df3.2 has the first date of week column w/ 117 rows. Now I try to merge these two columns into one because they have some overlapped first_date of week. any way to do that???

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: What's your intended output for these two tables?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to remove duplicated `first_date`?